# How to define discrete action space with continuous values in OpenAI Gym?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, implementation

I am trying to use a reinforcement learning solution in an OpenAI Gym environment that has 6 discrete actions with continuous values, e.g. increase parameter 1 with 2.2, decrease parameter 1 with 1.6, decrease parameter 3 with 1 etc.

I have seen in this [code](https://github.com/notadamking/Stock-Trading-Environment/blob/master/env/StockTradingEnv.py) that such an action space was implemented as a continuous space where the first value is approximated to discrete values (e.g. 0 if it is < 1 or 2 if it is < 2 and > 1).

Does anybody know if the above solution is the correct way to implement such an action space? Or does Gym offer another way?

Comment: You could use a `spaces.Tuple` to do something similar. One space to control the discrete part and one space to control the continuous part. I don't think there is a "right" or "wrong" answer, as it depends on what exactly your environment is doing

Comment: @chappers Acoording to the description I provided, it seems that using a Tuple to create an action space composed of both discrete and continuous parts is more appropriate. However, as I understand from you, the approach I described is also useful. Can you provide an example how to create a Tuple space as you described?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a sample environment which demonstrates this. It relies on the environment to successfully filter out the correct continuous control element

````py
import gym
from gym.spaces import Dict, Discrete, Box, Tuple
import numpy as np


class SampleGym(gym.Env):
    def __init__(self, config={}):
        self.config = config
        self.action_space = Tuple((Discrete(2), Box(-10, 10, (2,))))
        self.observation_space = Box(-10, 10, (2, 2))
        self.p_done = config.get("p_done", 0.1)

    def reset(self):
        return self.observation_space.sample()

    def step(self, action):
        chosen_action = action[0]
        cnt_control = action[1][chosen_action]

        if chosen_action == 0:
            reward = cnt_control
        else:
            reward = -cnt_control - 1

        print(f"Action, {chosen_action} continuous ctrl {cnt_control}")
        return (
            self.observation_space.sample(),
            reward,
            bool(np.random.choice([True, False], p=[self.p_done, 1.0 - self.p_done])),
            {},
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    env = SampleGym()
    env.reset()
    env.step((1, [-1, 2.1]))  # should say use action 1 with 2.1
    env.step((0, [-1.1, 2.1]))  # should say use action 0 with -1.1
```
````

Comment: Do you know which ready-to-use agents support a tuple action space? I tried with stable baselines 3 but none of their models seem to support it