# Understanding action space in stable baselines

Tags: reinforcement-learning, implementation, openai-gym

I was trying to write reinforcement learning agent using [stable-baselines3](https://github.com/araffin/rl-tutorial-jnrr19) library. The `agent(abservations)` method should return action. I went through different models API (like [PPO](https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/blob/master/stable_baselines3/ppo/ppo.py)) and they do not really allow us to specify action space. Instead action space is [specified in environment](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/72515/how-to-define-discrete-action-space-with-continuous-values-in-openai-gym).

[This](https://github.com/araffin/rl-tutorial-jnrr19/blob/sb3/1_getting_started.ipynb) notebook says:

> The type of action to use (discrete/continuous) will be automatically deduced from the environment action space.

So, it seems that "model" deduce action space from environment.

**Q1.** But exactly how?

**Q2.** Also how my `agent(observations)` method should return action? By returning action returned by `model.predict()`?

Comment: In case you don't get any answer here, you could try asking on https://ai.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I guess I got answer to Q1. Sharing my understanding below:

- `PPO` [extends](https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/blob/237223f834fe9b8143ea24235d087c4e32addd2f/stable_baselines3/ppo/ppo.py#L16) `OnPolicyAlgorithm`
- `PPO` [calls](https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/blob/237223f834fe9b8143ea24235d087c4e32addd2f/stable_baselines3/ppo/ppo.py#L95) `super(..,env,..)`, that is `OnPolicyAlgorithm(..,env,..)`
- `OnPolicyAlgorithm` [extends](https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/blob/237223f834fe9b8143ea24235d087c4e32addd2f/stable_baselines3/common/on_policy_algorithm.py#L18) `BaseAlgorithm`
- `OnPolicyAlgorithm` [calls](https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/blob/237223f834fe9b8143ea24235d087c4e32addd2f/stable_baselines3/common/on_policy_algorithm.py#L76) `super(..,env,..)`, that is `BaseAlgorithm(..,env,..)`
- `BaseAlgorithm` [seems to obtain](https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/blob/237223f834fe9b8143ea24235d087c4e32addd2f/stable_baselines3/common/base_class.py#L159) `action_space` from `env`

Still I am unable to get answer Q2.

Answer (score 0):

In short, in RL we develop an agent that interacts with an environment by generating actions that have an effect to the environment. So the agent perceives the state of the environment e.g. by using a Neural Network and outputs the relevant action.

For your first question take a look at the [Openai pendulum environment](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/c8a659369d98706b3c98b84b80a34a832bbdc6c0/gym/envs/classic_control/pendulum.py#L24).

For your second question yes `model.predict(observation)` does exactly this. If you think that every model is a NN with input observations then the output will be an action (sometimes implicitly as you might get expected values as outputs and use them to define your action selection policy).

Comment: My first question was about how agent knows actions. I guess the answer which I gave is correct one. Yes I believe you answered second question correctly. One off topic question, can you please point me to the multi agent reinforcement learning tutorial?